# Problems with usb wireless keyb+mouse after starting with a usb pendrive on (from an ubuntu 17.04 HDD)

Tags: wireless, usb, keyboard, mouse, logitech

I had no troubles before with my ubuntu 17.04 install, but after using a pendrive and leaving it on by mistake during a reboot, I cannot use the logitech wireless keyboard and mouse unit K400r anymore. (although it works fine at the Bios before loading Ubuntu).
I had the same problem (most probably caused the same way) in 14.04 and I updated twice because of it...
I did not had it again since the update to 17.04 until today....
I installed Solaar trying to fix this in 14.04 (to no avail) and left it after the update got it working as I find it helpful...

Comment: Some hardware combinations unfortunately results in odd behaviors that are very hard to troubleshoot. On top of that it may not have to do with Ubuntu but with how the BIOS/UEFI releases control to the OS and sometimes what solves it is a BIOS or UEFI update. If there's none, bette not to have the USB pen connected at boot (really, there's no need),

Comment: Yes now I know not to leave the USB drive on at boot... But how do I get the  Keyboard to work again? Fortunatelly any other (wired) keyboard and  mouse work just fine...

Comment: Sometimes reconnecting works.

Comment: not this time I'm afraid. I've also tried unplugging while off and rebooting of course...